# Can windows create internet shortcut of a local file on its own?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, file-shortcut

I found a internet shortcut for one of my file (an encrypted folder which was available on my drive) on my windows 10.  And i never had created such internet shortcut.  So is there any reason why would windows create such shortcut on its own?

Comment: What is the shortcut that was created?

Comment: An internet shortcut file

Comment: Probably a site you went to. Windows does not make shortcuts randomly on its own - only things that you (we) do.

Comment: Site?why will a website create such? Does it mean that the website has accessed that file

Comment: I have not seen any website I use create a shortcut but there may be one. Neither have I seen Windows make random shortcuts.

Comment: You might wish to scan fully for viruses, or see if there is some legacy software that is doing this.